# Tmux: check exit code of command that was sent by send-keys

Tags: tmux

I have these commands in a zsh script:

```
tmux select-pane -t 0
tmux send-keys 'repeat 5; do print This is a test; sleep 1; done' Enter
```

The tmux's send-keys itself just sends string to the pane but does not know that status of that `string` - the exit code.

How can I know when `repeat 5; do print This is a test; sleep 1; done` is done?

EDIT: The problem that I've faced that the result of `repeat 5; do print This is a test; sleep 1; done` affects the next `send-keys` command - meaning I have calculate myself how long the `repeat 5; do print This is a test; sleep 1; done` consume and put `sleep <seconds_repeat_consume>` to wait the `repeat` command completed before do the next `send-keys`.

Comment: This is not easy to do with tmux. You should instead look at getting the shell in the tmux session to do something when it has finished, eg add to your send-keys `;echo $? >file` then your script can look in that file for the exit code. But perhaps if you explain your original problem you may get more appropriate answer.

Comment: I'll edit the question. @meuh

Answer (score 1):

Getting the actual exit code may be hard. But it looks like you just need to know your command finished, in which case you can use [`tmux wait-for`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#MISCELLANEOUS).

Something like this:

```
tmux select-pane -t 0
tmux send-keys \
    'repeat 5; do print This is a test; sleep 1; done; tmux wait-for -S 0' Enter
tmux wait-for 0
echo 'Loop finished'
```

This will cause `tmux wait-for 0` to hang until tmux gets to the `tmux wait-for -S 0` part.

Comment: Nice! It would be awesome if it was possible to pass the status code too